# Texture mapping bitmap to SVG path

Tags: svg

I have an ordinary rectangular bitmap which I would like to be able to use to fill a four-pointed SVG path - basically a mapped texture so that the four corners of the bitmap are mapped to the four points of the path and the rest of the image is 'warped' accordingly.

I have been able to fill an SVG rect with the same image and then transform the rect such that the bitmap is transformed with it:

```
<defs>
  <pattern id="bmp" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
    <image x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" href="mybmp.bmp"/>
  </pattern>
</defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="url(#bmp)" stroke="black" transform="skewX(10)"/>
```

When I try to use the bitmap to fill a path though it gets mapped to the bounding box of the path shape and not the four points of the path itself:

```
<defs>
  <pattern id="bmp" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
    <image x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" href="mybmp.bmp"/>
  </pattern>
</defs>
<path d="M 0 0 L 100 0 L 120 80 L 50 120 Z" fill="url(#bmp)" stroke="black" />
```

Is it possible to get the same effect as the first example (texture properly mapped to the all corners of the rectangle) in an arbitrary path shape?

Comment: No, SVG does not suport non-affine transforms.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Looks like I'll have to try something else.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to give your pattern a `viewBox` so that its content image gets scaled to fit the pattern bounds.

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <pattern id="bmp" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1"
             viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <image x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" xlink:href="http://www.placekitten.com/100/100"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <path d="M 0 0 L 100 0 L 120 80 L 50 120 Z" fill="url(#bmp)" stroke="black" />
</svg>
```

Depending on the shape of your path, you may also need to set `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"`.  This will ensure that the pattern gets scaled to a size large enough to cover the whole path with no gaps.

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <pattern id="bmp" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1"
             viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
      <image x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" xlink:href="http://www.placekitten.com/100/100"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <path d="M 0 0 L 100 0 L 120 80 L 50 120 Z" fill="url(#bmp)" stroke="black" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. That wasn't quite what I was after though. Rather than covering at least the whole path, I wanted to be able to warp the image like a 3d texture - a non-affine transform, apparently (might have helped if I'd known the right term!)